# SQL Server : two similar DISTINCT queries result in a different execution plans

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, distinct, sql-execution-plan

My question is about execution plan built by SQL Server for a `DISTINCT` query.

I have a table in my database called `MainTable` with two columns: `Id (PK, int, not null)` and `Name (nvarchar(200), not null)`.

I run the following query (generated by Entity Framework)

```
SELECT 
    [Project2].[Id] AS [Id]
FROM   
    (SELECT 
         [Distinct1].[Id] AS [Id]
     FROM   
         (SELECT DISTINCT 
              [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id]
          FROM   
              [dbo].[TableA] AS [Extent1]
          INNER JOIN 
              [dbo].[TableB] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[TableAId]
          INNER JOIN 
              [dbo].[MainTable] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[MainTableId] = [Extent3].[Id]
          WHERE  
              [Extent1].[TableCId] = 48 /*  @p__linq__0 */) AS [Distinct1]) AS [Project2]
```

This creates a very inefficient [execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGL5S.png).

It uses nested loops and adds `TOP` statement although it is not present in the original query. It takes several seconds to run on a 2-3k records in the tables and does a lot of reads.

I tried running a similar query but with `DISTINCT` on `Name` column and the results appeared to be much better. So this query:

```
SELECT [Project2].[Name]          AS [Name]
FROM   (SELECT [Distinct1].[Name]          AS [Name]
    FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT [Extent3].[Name]          AS [Name]
            FROM   [dbo].[TableA] AS [Extent1]
                   INNER JOIN [dbo].[TableB] AS [Extent2]
                     ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[TableAId]
                   INNER JOIN [dbo].[MainTable] AS [Extent3]
                     ON [Extent2].[MainTableId] = [Extent3].[Id]
            WHERE  [Extent1].[TableCId] = 48 /* @p__linq__0 */) AS [Distinct1]) AS [Project2]
```

results in a much more efficient in my case

[excecution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH436.png)

using Hash Match

So I wonder what is the difference between making `DISTINCT` on `Id` and `Name`, why is it adding `TOP` statement and how do I make the first query more efficient?

Thanks

**Update**

Using `SELECT DISTINCT [Extent2].[MainTableId]` instead of `SELECT DISTINCT [Extent3].[Id]` produces the second, more efficient execution plan.

Comment: Without seeing the table definition (including indexes) it is guesswork.

Comment: The only way to answer this kind of question is to have access to the database in question. There could be a ton of things that are different that you're not telling us, but here's a couple: Indexes on the columns in questions, the selectivity of the columns in question in those indexes.

Comment: I would look at indexes on the table as well as the sparsity of the fields in question, the Id column is unique, but the Name column may not be, so an index on it may be faster... this is just conjecture though, so you might want to do a little research on the differences of those fields in relation to the dataset as a whole.

Comment: It looks like these statements are being created by LINQ.  In my experience, the SQL statements being created by LINQ are rarely optimized properly.  In your case, it looks like the @p__linq__0 variable is causing your trouble.  SQL has absolutely NO idea what that value is so it can't put together a good execution plan.  I'm not 100% sure what your options are, through LINQ, to parameterize this or clean up it's execution plan.

Comment: All variables should be bound or otherwise typed, so the datatype will be known when it is executed. In this particular example, it has even been replaced with a literal integer. There shouldn't be any problems with that.

Comment: if you do `SET STATISTICS IO ON` then run the two queries, can you show the output of the IO information for them? I would be willing to put money on the fact that the one you think is faster actually is slower and uses more IO